# Read information that has been couted to the terminal

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to figure out how to read information from the terminal or console, (I am using ubuntu)
I am not looking for `cin`, or `readline`.
I don't want user input, instead I want a program that will read text that is written in the terminal by `cout`, `put_char` etc... How can this information be accessed by a C++ program?

edit:
say I have a program that

```
int main(...)
{
    cout << blahblahblah;
    ....
}
```

how can I read the information that was sent to the terminal?

```
int someFunc()
{
     someIostream terminal;
     string = terminal.readline();
}
```

Or as another example
suppose I have some user who has been running things on their terminal
and I want to see everything they typed in before running my program

Comment: You're going to have to give a more concrete example. It's not clear exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Once the data goes to `cout`, you can't fetch it back.  If your operating system or platform support, you could loop the output channel to the input channel.  Another method is to tell the operating system to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Let's take a step back, a big step back.  Your program generates data that goes to `cout`.  Your program should save this data somewhere so it can read it back.  Now what was that called that allowed read and write capabilities, a *file* perhaps?

Comment: yes, one could modify `cout` so that it writes to a file instead, using `ofstream foo` and setting `cout.rdbuf(foo.rdbuf())` but i don't want to do that, I want to read information that is in the terminal. It still exists and must be accessible some how as I can use my mouse copy paste the information elsewhere. So there has to be some method for retrieving it.

Comment: @TorstenGang You can copy/paste using your mouse because the program that emulates the terminal provide this option to its user. Your software doesn't know if there is such program running. Your software could be directly connected to a real tty and someone took the printed page away with him. So absolutely nobody can tell what was written by your software.

Comment: @TorstenGang The information output to terminal is not easily accessible because it is an _output_ device. There are other devices you can use for easy input and output. Again, the first thing that pops into one's mind is _file_.

Comment: In two words, you cannot. A terminal is a fancy typewriter. Once a letter is printed, you need to be physically there and look at the physical paper with your physical eye in order to read it. The fact that the paper is now made of pixels in most cases, and that some program somewhere probably stores some representation of printed output, changes nothing. You cannot just tap into an arbitrary program and steal its internal data you know nothing about.